# Random arrangements in a line

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

been having some trouble with this, not sure if I'm on the right track.

5 numbers are chosen uniformly at random from {1, 2, . . . , 10} and arranged uniformly at random in a line. What is the probability that the numbers appear in increasing order?

Am I correct in saying that the probability is  10C5 / (10C5 * 5!)  = 1 /5! ?

My thinking is that there are 10C5 possible combinations of numbers, and for each of those combinations there is only one arrangement in ascending order. Additionally there are 5! ways of arranging each possible combination, so the final probability is 1/5! ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Once you pick $5$ numbers, there is $1$ way to arrange them in increasing order, while there are $5!$ ways to order them.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much!